# $F:R^n$ to $R^n$ is a norm-preserving linear operator. Prove that $F(x)*F(y)=x*y$ for all $x,y$ in $R$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, normed-spaces

$F:R^n$ to $R^n$ is a norm-preserving linear operator. Prove that $F(x)*F(y)=x*y$ for all $x,y$ in $R$

Attempt:
$||F(x+y)||^2=||x+y||^2=||F(x)||^2+||F(y)||^2+2x*y$

Then I'm stuck and don't know where to go.

Comment: You're close. Instead of swapping $\|F(x)\|$ and $\|x\|$ in one equation, write down two full equations of this form: One using only $F(x)$, $F(y)$  and $F(x+y)$ and the other using $x,y$ and $x+y$

Comment: @T_M thanks! got it